# what is the use of xmlns in oozie?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am new to Oozie and trying to understand what exactly xmlns in the below line means, in an oozie workflow?

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4"
```

I know what xmlns is but in this context there is some uri ending with some number. What does it refer to?

Comment: RTFM - https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#Appendix_A_Oozie_XML-Schema >> is that a coincidence that "schema V0.5" specification is tagged `"uri:oozie:workflow:0.5"`??

Comment: I think the version of oozie mentioned in the xmlns is important, as it directly maps to oozie version (https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#Appendix_A_Oozie_XML-Schema). I remember having a problem with oozie SLAs when i was using an older name space version.

Answer (score 2):

This number refers to the oozie workflow schema version. Schema defines the xml pattern to define any action in workflow.

Currently followings schemas are available:

```
Oozie Schema Version 0.5
Oozie Schema Version 0.4.5
Oozie Schema Version 0.4
Oozie Schema Version 0.3
Oozie Schema Version 0.2.5
Oozie Schema Version 0.2
Oozie SLA Version 0.2
Oozie SLA Version 0.1
Oozie Schema Version 0.1
```

You can refer [Oozie workflow Schema manual](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#Appendixes) for details